# UriMapper not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, uri

i am working on Wp7 app.Here I am using uriMapper to direct user to the start page depending upon the condition.

And the condition is that

if he has registered he should directly go to mypage2.xaml 
   if he has not registered then he should go to mypage1.xaml

So to resolve this i used UriMapper in app.xaml

```
    <uriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/InermediatePage.xaml" />
    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
```

InermediatePage.xaml  is just an intermediate page which does nothing.

and my code in the constructor of app.xaml.cs is 
   LoadActivePage();

```
 private void LoadActivePage()
    {
        UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
        RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;

        if(ifNotRegistered)
        {
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri= new Uri("/mypage1.xaml",UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else
        {
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri= new Uri("/mypage2.xaml",UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is  when i debug .. it works fine.

But when my app is tombstoned and restart the app in emulator or device
   it shows Inermediatepage.xaml
 instead of showing mypage1.xaml or mypage2.xaml

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Activated Event in the App.xaml.cs? You might need to add code to this event handler.